# Twitter login Page in Android Application when check the check box

Tags: android, twitter

Hi i need twitter Login Screen. when i check the check box i need to get Twitter login Page.

Please help me as a Sample code.

**EDIT:**

I tried this, but getting the force close.
Here is my logcat:

```
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222): java.lang.VerifyError: com.android.twitter.TwitterApp
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at com.android.twitter.TwitterActivity.onCreate(TwitterActivity.java:34)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-30 17:02:30.901: E/AndroidRuntime(3222):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank You in Advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Just check whether you jars are in lib folder or libs folder.I was also facing the same problem I just changed the jar from lib to libs and problem was solved. I hope it works for you too.